# Is $\exists a \in \mathbb F \forall v \in V (av = 0)$ an axiom of vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, axioms

Is the statement $0\cdot x = 0$ for all $x \in V$ an axiom of the theory of vector spaces? I understand it is implied by the distributivity laws: $$0\cdot x = (1-1)\cdot x = x - x = 0$$ But, can I say it is an axiom too?

Comment: I think you need it as an axiom in order to prove $(-1)\cdot v=-v$ which you have used implicitly in your "proof". The distributivity law is usually $(a+b)\cdot v= a\cdot v+b\cdot v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this as an axiom. Since $0v=(0+0)v=0v+0v$ and $(V,+)$ is a group, it follows that $0v=0$. I usually use four axioms for the scalar multiplication: $1v=v$, $(a+b)v=av+bv$, $a(v+w)=av+aw$ and $(ab)v=a(bv)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I was looking for. From the viewpoint of logic, is it ok to call theorems of a theory also axioms? Or are axioms thought of as a "basis" in some sense?

Comment: Axioms are statements which cannot be proven within a certain theory. Most prominently the axiom of choice in ZF set theory. Most mathematicians try to use as few axioms as possible (since Euclid, people tried to prove the parallel "postulate" until Gauss showed that it is impossible). Theorems are the statements which can be deduced from axioms.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ${0 \cdot x = 0}$ is one of the multiplicative axioms for vector spaces. Depending on the text that defines the axioms they sometimes include it already as an axiom. The approach you did is valid.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.